# Suggestion needed for iPhone Map based App Development?

Tags: iphone, maps

Hii friends,

i have to create a routemap for a university using maps as i preferred to use Google Maps API to develop it, as it seems easy for me with previous experience with maps API.

Does any Map library available for iPhone beyong google maps?

Comment: thanks thomas, i m new user , sure i would then,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hey do try Route Me and open source library
http://mobileorchard.com/route-me-an-open-source-map-library-for-iphone-developers/